# How to make a style for paragraphs with hanging indents

Tags: formatting, stylesheet

I am making slides with text.  I created a style template, but I cannot see how to make a style for a hanging paragraph.  Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 2):

Within a Text Cell you can use [`ParagraphIndent`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ParagraphIndent.html).  A negative value will produce a hanging paragraph.  A stylesheet entry:

```
Cell[StyleData["Text"],
  ParagraphIndent -> -50
]
```

The result:

[image]

See also [`LineIndent`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/LineIndent.html).