# Grid questions: text-wrapping / copying and pasting expressions

Tags: evaluation, grid-layouts, copy-as, text-formatting

I want to make a list of functions like this:

```
functionList = 
  {{Style["Function", Larger, Bold], Style["Notes", Larger, Bold], 
 Style["Source", Larger, Bold]}, 
  {"f[n]=a", "Long long long long description - I'd like it to wrap within the cell", "Wikipedia"}, 
  {"g[n]=b", "I'd like to be able to select this function and copy-and-paste", 
 "Wikipedia"}, 
  {"\[VerticalEllipsis]", "\[VerticalEllipsis]", "\[VerticalEllipsis]"}}; 

Grid[functionList, Alignment -> {Left, Top}, Spacings -> {2, 2}, Frame -> All]
```

[image]

I have two questions:

1. I need a way of setting the cell-widths, and then instructing text to wrap within that width. Is this possible? I don't think [this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/89502/control-line-wrapping-within-a-grid-cell) is quite what I'm after - at least, I can't see how to apply it.
2. I'd like to be able to select a function from the outputted `Grid` and copy it so I can paste it elsewhere. Is there a way to do this, without actually forcing Mathematica to evaluate the expression? I could write `f[n]==a` instead of `"f[n]=a"`, for example, and it would appear in copy-and-pastable form; but then Mathematica would evaluate it, which I want to avoid.

Thanks in advance for your suggestions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `TextGrid` with the `ItemSize` option:

```
TextGrid[
 functionList,
 Alignment -> {Left, Top},
 Spacings -> {2, 2},
 Frame -> All,
 ItemSize -> {{5, 30, 10}, Automatic}
 ]
```

You could also use the `ItemSize` option with `Grid`, but `TextGrid` looks a bit better, and also it takes care of the copy-and-paste problem that you encountered.